# How to grab data from Json data in API

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

I would like to grab data which has a `name` tag by calling JSON data by using Ajax. But now a function `showCard` does not work correctly. How can I get the data which has a `name` tag? When you click a `img` which has`found`, I would like to grab data from an API, and show its name by innerHTML. But now nothing happens when you click it.
p.s. Its id is added in the function `populatePokedex`. Hopefully, this question makes sense. Thanks.

```
(function() {
'use strict';

window.onload = function(){
    populatePokedex(); // <- This works correctly

    var $foundPics = document.getElementsByClassName("found");
    for(var i = 0; i < $foundPics.length; i++){
        $foundPics[i].onclick = showCard;
    }
};



// populate Pokedex
function populatePokedex() {

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", "https://webster.cs.washington.edu/pokedex/pokedex.php?pokedex=all");
    xhr.onload = function(){
        if (this.status == 200) {
            var picArr = this.responseText.split("\n");
            for(var i=0; i < picArr.length; i++){
                var eachName = picArr[i].split(":");
                var spriteurl = "/Pokedex/sprites/" + eachName[1];
                var imgClass = 'sprite';
                if(eachName[1]==='bulbasaur.png' || eachName[1]==='charmander.png' || eachName[1]==='squirtle.png'){
                    imgClass += ' found';
                } else {
                    imgClass += ' unfound';
                }
                document.getElementById("pokedex-view").innerHTML += "<img src=\"" + spriteurl + "\" id=\"" + eachName[0] + "\" class=\"" + imgClass + "\">";
            }
        } else {
            document.getElementById("pokedex-view").innerHTML = "ERROR: Status: " + this.status + ", " + this.statusText;
        }
    };
    xhr.onerror = function(){
        document.getElementById("pokedex-view").innerHTML = "ERROR";
    };
    xhr.send();
}


// if the pokemon is found, it shows the data of the pokemon
function showCard() {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = "https://webster.cs.washington.edu/pokedex/pokedex.php?pokemon=" + this.id;
    xhr("GET", url);
    xhr.onload = function(){
        var data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        var pokeName = document.getElementsByClassName("name");
        for(var i=0; i < pokeName.length; i++){
            pokeName[i].innerHTML = data.name;
        }
    };
    xhr.onerror = function(){
        alert("ERROR");
    };
    xhr.send();

}


})();
```

Part of HTML is listed below;

```
  <div id="my-card">

    <div class="card-container">
      <div class="card">
        <h2 class="name">Pokemon Name</h2>
        <img src="icons/fighting.jpg" alt="weakness" class="weakness" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- You populate this using JavaScript -->
  <div id="pokedex-view"></div>
```

Comment: what happens if you declare `data` like this: `var data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);` ?

Comment: I tried, but it did not work...

Comment: any specifics about what is not working? is `showCard` method callled? because `populatePokedex` has async http request inside it.

Comment: it looks like you can just get the `id` inside your click event listener.  instead of a `for` loop to assign click events, use an event listener like this `document.querySelector('.found').addEventListener('click', showCard)` to assign that listener to every `<div class="found"></div>`

Comment: I tried the code, but the console says there is an error in the code of querySelector...

Comment: Also I added i little more information on the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few issues in you JS for `showCard`

I have coded a simple solution.  I added some brief explanations in the code (as comments)

```js
(function() {
  'use strict';

  window.onload = function() {
    populatePokedex(); // <- This works correctly
    
    // adding event listeners to dynamically added nodes.
    document.querySelector('body').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
      // need to target only elements with class found (but unfound would also match the indexOf below, so we changed the name of the matching class slightly)
      if (event.target.className.toLowerCase().indexOf('founded') != -1) {
        showCard();
      }
    });
  };


  // populate Pokedex
  function populatePokedex() {

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", "https://webster.cs.washington.edu/pokedex/pokedex.php?pokedex=all");
    xhr.onload = function() {
      if (this.status == 200) {
        var picArr = this.responseText.split("\n");
        for (var i = 0; i < picArr.length; i++) {
          var eachName = picArr[i].split(":");
          var spriteurl = "https://webster.cs.washington.edu/pokedex/sprites/" + eachName[1];
          var imgClass = 'sprite';
          if (eachName[1] === 'bulbasaur.png' || eachName[1] === 'charmander.png' || eachName[1] === 'squirtle.png') {
            imgClass += ' founded';
          } else {
            imgClass += ' unfound';
          }
          document.getElementById("pokedex-view").innerHTML += "<img src=\"" + spriteurl + "\" id=\"" + eachName[0] + "\" class=\"" + imgClass + "\">";
        }
      } else {
        document.getElementById("pokedex-view").innerHTML = "ERROR: Status: " + this.status + ", " + this.statusText;
      }
    };
    xhr.onerror = function() {
      document.getElementById("pokedex-view").innerHTML = "ERROR";
    };
    xhr.send();
  }

  // if the pokemon is found, it shows the data of the pokemon
  function showCard() {
    
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    // since you are in a click event, use the target's id instead
    var url = "https://webster.cs.washington.edu/pokedex/pokedex.php?pokemon=" + event.target.id;
    // there was an error here
    xhr.open("GET", url);
    xhr.onload = function() {
      // parse the response text into JSON
      var data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
      // update the element with this id with a new value from the response data
      document.getElementById("pokemon-name").innerHTML = data.name;
    };
    xhr.onerror = function() {
      alert("ERROR");
    };
    xhr.send();

  }




})();
```

```css
.founded:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.founded {
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div id="my-card">

  <div class="card-container">
    <div class="card">
      <h2 id="pokemon-name" class="name">Pokemon Name</h2>
      <img src="https://webster.cs.washington.edu/pokedex/icons/fighting.jpg" alt="weakness" class="weakness" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- You populate this using JavaScript -->
<div id="pokedex-view"></div>
```

Comment: @Tak I am glad I could help, I added some comments explaining what the issues were

Answer (score 2):

When I use your url: https://webster.cs.washington.edu/pokedex/pokedex.php?pokemon=mew, I got this data:

```
{"name":"Mew","hp":160,"info":{"id":"151","type":"psychic","weakness":"dark","description":"Its DNA is said to contain the genetic codes of all Pokemon."},"images":{"photo":"images\/mew.jpg","typeIcon":"icons\/psychic.jpg","weaknessIcon":"icons\/dark.jpg"},"moves":[{"name":"Amnesia","type":"psychic"},{"name":"Psychic","dp":90,"type":"psychic"}]}
```

Assuming you want to display the word mew, data.name or data['name'] works fine.
What I'm suspecting is that `document.getElementsByClassName("name").innerHTML` 
does not exist or something along that line. Could I see the error message that appears when the function is run or show your HTML portion as well?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I added part of my HTML code on the question.

Comment: @Tak 
Can you try something like this
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("name");
    x[0].innerHTML = data.name;

Comment: @Tak , alternatively rather than by class name, if the 'name' is not going to be repeated you could change it to id rather than class.

Comment: Thank you. The html is provided, and I cannot modify that... and I'm wondering if 'this.id' in the function showCard is working well. Can I get the id of the element from this.id??

Comment: @Tak could you try changing  document.getElementsByClassName("name").innerHTML = data.name; to var x = document.getElementsByClassName("name"); x[0].innerHTML = data.name;

Comment: I edited my code based on your suggestion, and put the latest one on the question.. but it is still not working...

Comment: If you add an alert(this.id) inside showcard function, does it alert when you click on a card to show?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comments! And another member could solve the problem! Thank you!

Comment: @Tak , no problem, glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using the below to declare the "click"

```
$foundPics[i].onclick = showCard;
```

You should bind an event listener like this

```
$foundPics[i].addEventListener('click', showCard());
```

Aside from this you xhr.open() method is in the wrong place. The standard way of using it is to put it just before your send() call.

Hope this helps